# how to reset a php count on each new post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to write a function that does two usages of a count. It's easier to see the code to understand what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$i = 1;

while ($jobs->have_posts()) : $jobs->the_post();
   $i++;

   $html_out .= '<tr class="row-'. $i .'">';
   $html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $i++ .'"></td>';
   $html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $i++ .'"></td>';
   $html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $i++ .'"></td>';
   $html_out .= '</tr>';
endwhile;
```

The code here is incomplete, but I hope this is enough to get the idea across. So outside of the while I have a `<tr>` with the class `row-1`. In the while I wanted the first post's `<tr>` to start `row-2` and keep incrementing from there.

Inside the `<tr>` I have `<td>`'s with column classes. I need them to start with `column-1` and increment from there, but on a new post it'll keep counting, so the second post's first `<td>` will output at `column-4`, but I need it to reset back to `column-1`.

I hope this makes sense. This is an example of the desired output for a post within the `while`:

```
<tr class="row-2">
   <td class="column-1"></td>
   <td class="column-2"></td>
   <td class="column-3"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-3">
   <td class="column-1"></td>
   <td class="column-2"></td>
   <td class="column-3"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-4">
   <td class="column-1"></td>
   <td class="column-2"></td>
   <td class="column-3"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two indexes and reset column index at each iteration:

```
$row = 2;

while ($jobs->have_posts()) : $jobs->the_post();

   $col = 1;

   $html_out .= '<tr class="row-'. $row .'">';
   $html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $col++ .'"></td>';
   $html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $col++ .'"></td>';
   $html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $col++ .'"></td>';
   $html_out .= '</tr>';

   $row++;

endwhile;
```

Comment: This is it, thanks! I have a much better understanding of how to count.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two counters, as follows:

```
$row = 1;

while ($jobs->have_posts()) : $jobs->the_post();
   $column = 1;

   $html_out .= '<tr class="row-'. $row++ .'">';
   $html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $column++ .'"></td>';
   $html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $column++ .'"></td>';
   $html_out .= '<td class="column-'. $column .'"></td>'; //this one will be reset to 1 in the next interation, no need to increment
   $html_out .= '</tr>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: The only thing I'd have to fix here is what @Paolo did, which was making the class for the row `row-'.$row.'` and placing `$row++` outside of that so it didn't start at `1` but skipped it and started from `2`.